# MIDL: не генерирует *.h файлы для разделенных *.IDL файлов

Tags: c++

До тех пор пока в проекте VC++2008 студии был всего один IDL файл все работало хорошо, но когда возникла необходимость разделить этот IDL файл (из-за ошибки большого размера) на несколько IDL файлов:

**Interface1.idl** file:

```
Interface Interface2; // forward declaration
#ifndef __Interface1_IDL_FILE_
#define __Interface1_IDL_FILE_
[
    object,
    uuid(66006A2F-B777-4e2f-A0CA-D5BE00000015),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface Interface1 : IUnknown{
    HRESULT getInterface2([out, retval]Interface2** outVal )
};
#endif
```

**Interface2.idl** file:

```
Interface Interface1;// forward delcarations
#ifndef __Interface2_IDL_FILE_
#define __Interface2_IDL_FILE_
[
    object,
    uuid(66006A2F-B777-4e2f-A0CA-D5BE00000015),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface Interface2 : IUnknown
{
    HRESULT getInterface1([out, retval]Interface1** outVal )
};
#endif
```

**AllInterface.idl** file:

```
import Interface1.idl
import Interface2.idl
```

**MyProject.idl** file:

```
import AllInterface.idl;
```

При компиляции для **MyProject.idl** файла генерируется **MyProject.h** где указано:

```
/* header files for imported files */
#include "oaidl.h"
#include "ocidl.h"
#include "AllInterface.h"
```

Но сам файл **AllInterface.h** не генерируется из **AllInterface.idl** файла и как следствие возникает ошибка компиляции:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'AllInterface.h': No such file or directory
```

Как заставить VC++2008 студию генерировать *.h файлы для промежуточных *.IDL файлов?

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу на свой же вопрос:

В случае когда в проекте несколько *.IDL файлов то их можно конфигурировать и компилировать по отдельности:

- Чтобы сконфигурировать Solution Explorer > Select IDL file > Right-Click > Properties, где можно указать какой .h файл и где он будет создан при компиляции этого IDL файла;
- Чтобы скомпилировать Solution Explorer > Select IDL file >  Right-Click > Compile;

Таким образом к моменту компиляции всего проекта с главным **MyProject.idl** файлом эти *.h файлы уже будут созданы и ошибок компиляции больше не будет.